# ElasticSearch Ngram tokenizer not working

Tags: elasticsearch

Below is a shortened version of my cfg mapping, using ngram tokenizer (I have not included all fields and only region below).

I have region data indexed as "Stuttgart" and "Munich" for two separate documents.
When I search for text either "Stut" or "tutt" it does not return me any documents.

Is there anything I am missing in the config ?

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "address": {
      "properties": {
        "region": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "address_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "address_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "address_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "address_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 4,
          "max_gram": 4,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It should work. Can you show your query?

Comment: My complete query is below: `{"query":{"multi_match":{"query":"Stut","fields":["postcode","country.name","country.country_code","country.geographical_name","country.economic_areas","full_country","locality","street","region","settings.analysis.tokenizer.address_tokenizer"]}}}`

Comment: Based on the info you gave in your question, I've created an index locally and indexed a document with `{"region": "Stuttgart"}` and the query returns me that document. Not sure what's wrong... Feel free to gist a complete recreation script so we can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @val Thank you. it seems to be working now (may be I had some stuff cached in my browser, since I was using graphiQL endpoint for testing). But this `ngram` tokenizer is case sensitive, do you know how to have this work for case insesitive ?

Comment: "filter" : [ "lowercase" ] does the job.